# Attaching to sendgrid api not working when using sendgrid mail helper

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I have looked through the questions i can find on here about attaching a file to a sendgrid email but none seem to have the issue I am.

My question is is this. How do you send an email with an attachment in sendgrid using the api?

```
 dynamic sg = new SendGridAPIClient(apiKey);
        var from = new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Email("jkennedy@domain.com");
        var subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid C# Library!";
        var to = new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Email(toAddress);
        var content = new Content("multipart/form-data", "Textual content");
        var attachment = new Attachment {Filename = attachmentPath };
        var mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

        var ret = mail.Get();

        mail.AddAttachment(attachment);


        dynamic response = await sg.client.mail.send.post(requestBody: ret);
```

If i put the mail.attachment after the get the mail sends but there is no attachment. If i put the addattachment line before the get i get a "bad request" message.

I have yet to find an example of exactly how to do this.

Also, the path to the file is c:\tblaccudatacounts.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. I was using a helper written by a third party.  I went with what with SendGrid actually suggested. See code below that is now working.

```
var myMessage = new SendGridMessage {From = new MailAddress("info@email.com")};
        myMessage.AddTo("Jeff Kennedy <info@info.com>");
        myMessage.Subject = "test email";
        myMessage.Html = "<p>See Attachedment for Lead</p>";
        myMessage.Text = "Hello World plain text!";
        myMessage.AddAttachment("C:\\tblaccudatacounts.csv");
        var apiKey = "apikey given by sendgrid";
        var transportWeb = new Web(apiKey);
        await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
```

Comment: Where did you get this code sample? The official API URL https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp suggests what @DStage31 suggested above.

Comment: SendGrid.Web.Web

Answer (score 3):

After struggling with this for a couple hours, I found an answer using sendgrid's V3 API. Here's what I learned.

In your example, you call `var ret = mail.Get();` before adding the attachment. Since `mail.Get()` is essentially serializing the mail object into the Json format SendGrid is expecting, adding the attachment after the `mail.Get()` call will not actually add it to the mail object.

The other thing you should know is that the API doesn't have a way of simply taking the file path as an input (At least that I can find, I hope someone can correct me). You need to manually set at least the content (as a base 64 string) and filename. You can find more information [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html).

Here is my working solution:

```
string apiKey = "your API Key";
dynamic sg = new SendGridAPIClient(apiKey);

Email from = new Email("your@domain.com");
string subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid CSharp Library!";
Email to = new Email("destination@there.com");
Content body = new Content("text/plain", "Hello, Email!");
Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, body);

byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/dev/datafiles/testData.txt");
string fileContentsAsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

var attachment = new Attachment
{
    Filename = "YourFile.txt",
    Type = "txt/plain",
    Content = fileContentsAsBase64
};

mail.AddAttachment(attachment);

dynamic response = await sg.client.mail.send.post(requestBody: mail.Get());
```

Comment: Yes from V3, they have introduced this Base64 encoded data for attachment. Prior to that it used to work fine.